# On IIS server making all content use HTTPS (avoiding mixed content)

Tags: ssl, iis, https

Is there a way to set up IIS to make all HTTP requests use HTTPS and avoid mixed content.

I realize that in page URLs can be rewritten or set up as protocol relative with the // at the beginning but I would like a solution that can deal with relative URLS in HTML and CSS like src="styles/style.css" and could work universally across many pages and all content.

Comment: If you use absolute paths IE `<img src=http://yoursite.com/image.jpg">` then your answer is no ..  The browser will look "externally" even if it comes from the same site .. It's always best practice to use relative paths: `<img src="/path/to/file/image.jpg">`

Comment: But if it is requesting a URL on your server then can't it be forced to use HTTPS in that case?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the server **responds** with ..  This is the client side (**browser**)  --  All the client cares about is the **outgoing** protocol --  In this case, it's **requesting** `http` while on a "secured" page = mixed content